# Measuring the monthly proportion of a sub-group from a categorical variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df structured as follows:

```
dput(head(control_group[(1:10)]))
```

output:

```
structure(list(post = c(date = structure(c(1299024000, 1299024000, 1299024000, 1299024000, 
1299024000, 1299024000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")),"), sentiment_human_coded = c("negative", 
"neutral", "negative", "neutral", "neutral", "negative"), economic_demand_complaint = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), socio_egotropic = c("sociotropic", "sociotropic", 
"sociotropic", "sociotropic", "sociotropic", "sociotropic"), 
    collective_action = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), treatment_details = c("pre", 
    "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre"), treatment_implementation = c("pre", 
    "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre"), month_year = structure(c(2011.16666666667, 
    2011.16666666667, 2011.16666666667, 2011.16666666667, 2011.16666666667, 
    2011.16666666667), class = "yearmon")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I am trying to measure the average share of negative sentiment in a given month, and I have tried the following way:

```
graph <- control_group %>%
  group_by(sentiment_human_coded, month_year) %>%   
  mutate(sentiment_month_count=n()) %>% #count of sentiment by month
  group_by(month_year) %>% 
  mutate(month_year_count=n())  %>% ###total count per month
  mutate(sentiment_percentage = sentiment_month_count/month_year_count*100) #percentage
```

The code works well but I don't think it's computing the indicator that I am interested in generating. More specifically, I am interested in having a new variable that would look as follows, where sentiment_count sums up all rows in a given month, and negative_share divides the number of negative sentiment observations by the monthly total:

```
month_year    sentiment_count  negative_count   negative_share
April 2022.   300               100              33.3%
May 2022.   400               100              25%
```

Using the neat solution by harre as follows:

```
 control_group %>%
  group_by(month_year) |>
  summarise(sentiment_count = n(),
            negative_count = sum(sentiment_human_coded == "negative"),
            negative_share = negative_count/sentiment_count * 100)
```

Provides this output, but is there a reason why the first month is NA using the summarise()?
I have checked my data and there are 123 negative cases in March 2011, yet are ignored by summarise()

```
month_year
<S3: yearmon>
sentiment_count
<int>
negative_count
<int>
negative_share
<dbl>
Mar 2011    272 NA  NA  
Apr 2011    62  23  37.09677    
Jun 2011    64  47  73.43750    
Oct 2011    307 283 92.18241    
Nov 2011    65  60  92.30769    
Mar 2012    60  55  91.66667    
Apr 2012    8   3   37.50000    
Jul 2012    10  9   90.00000    
Nov 2012    1   0   0.00000
```

Comment: I am afraid the "output" from `dput` is not working :)

Comment: Your example data is producing five rows with the two columns `date` and `month_year`, which are identical across all rows. It's missing the `sendiment` column, which I think is what you're aiming to count?

Comment: Apologies, and yes, that is correct. Are you able to see the updated data example? I am interested in counting the # of rows classified as negative under the "sentiment_human_coded" variable.
I hided two columns that contain private data.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
library(dplyr)

control_group |>
  group_by(month_year) |>
  summarise(sentiment_count = n(),
            negative_count = sum(sentiment_human_coded == "negative"),
            negative_share = negative_count/sentiment_count * 100)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 4
  month_year sentiment_count negative_count negative_share
  <yearmon>            <int>          <int>          <dbl>
1 2011.167                 6              3             50
```

Data:

```r
control_group <- structure(list(post = c(date = structure(c(1299024000, 1299024000, 1299024000, 1299024000, 
                                                            1299024000, 1299024000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct",                                                                                                              "POSIXt"))), sentiment_human_coded = c("negative", "neutral", "negative", "neutral", "neutral", "negative"), economic_demand_complaint = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), socio_egotropic = c("sociotropic", "sociotropic", 
"sociotropic", "sociotropic", "sociotropic", "sociotropic"), 
    collective_action = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), treatment_details = c("pre", 
    "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre"), treatment_implementation = c("pre", 
    "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre"), month_year = structure(c(2011.16666666667, 
    2011.16666666667, 2011.16666666667, 2011.16666666667, 2011.16666666667, 
    2011.16666666667), class = "yearmon")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```